# How to handle exception in a apache beam pipeline?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am building a apache beam pipeline in java which does a bunch of stuff like reading files , creating audits and loading it to bigquery. I want to move the files to some other folder if my pipeline fails at any step. So basically if my pipeline fails at any step due to any reason i want to handle it in below if condition. Currently If the pipeline runs successfully then it is going in the else part and printing Done, but if pipeline fails it shows exit code 1 but failed is not printed. Is there a way to handle my pipeline failure like this.

```
 PipelineResult.State state = pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
 if(state == PipelineResult.State.FAILED){
            System.out.println("failed");
        }else if(state==PipelineResult.State.DONE){

           

            System.out.println("Done");

        }
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What runner are you using? Is an exception being thrown (that you could presumably catch)?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at how to handle errors at each step of the pipeline rather than trying to handle the pipeline failing.

The WriteToBigQuery sink for example has a default retry strategy of always so errors will always be retried even if they are not in a format that can be successfully written to BigQuery. You could look at implementing the dead letter pattern to catch errors and write them to a different source.

I have only worked with Kafka and PubSub as the inputs to a pipeline so I'm not sure how errors would be handled when reading from files and what problems you might encounter.

When creating audits or any other processing steps between reading and writing the data you could use tagged outputs and try catches to create two different outputs from a step for successful and failed outputs then write them to wherever you like